# Trying to use ASP.NET WebHooks framework to receieve a WebHook from Vend API

Tags: c#, webhooks

I am trying to find a **good** implementation of how to use [ASP.NET WebHooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/) in C# to receive WebHooks from the [Vend API](https://docs.vendhq.com/docs/webhooks).

I checked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers), but the example is not tailored to anything except pre-existing NuGet package receievers (Instagram, GitHub, etc..)

I also checked out the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom) which was also not the answer because it is only for applications receiving custom WebHooks from actual ***ASP.NET WebHooks*** (lol). Not for actual *custom WebHooks* such as Vend.

<s>I also checked out [here](https://github.com/chipwillman/VendAPI.Net/tree/master/VendHook) but unfortunately this example is **outdated**</s>.

I even went through the whole [WebHooks book](https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/aspnet_webhooks_succinctly) and could not find one implementation of a WebHook receiver that did not already have a NuGet Package tied to it..

In the comments, the author Gaurav Aroraa, who wrote the book I refer to above says:

> "If you need a specific receiver raise request in GitHuv repository
>   someone add one."

[At the bottom of the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers) ^

So does this mean I just need to request one to be made? Or is there a generic type of implementation around some where that I am missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were on a private network and I wasn't thinking about that, therefore we were unable to receive WebHooks from Vend. The solution was to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to publicly host a url to test with, also follow the guidelines of the solution [here](https://github.com/chipwillman/VendAPI.Net/tree/master/VendHook), it works perfectly and is less of a hassle then Microsoft's WebHooks *and* is already tailored to work for Vend.

Comment: do you know if webhooks work during the trial period on a new account? I'm having a hard time testing it for a client.

Comment: @PetrusTheron sorry for the late response, but yes they do work for the trial accounts.